# extending shared_ptr by inheritance

Tags: c++, boost, shared-ptr

What is so bad about doing something like this?

```
class myclass : public std::shared_ptr<myotherclass> {
     // some code,  an allocation is never done
     std::string get_info () {
          if(*this != nullptr) return "<info>" + (this->info * 3) + "</info>";
          else return "";
     }
 };
```

when no allocation is done in  the class --- it is just to provide some decoration like above?

Comment: What is so good about doing something like this ?

Comment: In most cases you should be able to describe the inheritance relationship with the English phase "is a".  So in the above case what you are saying is: myclass "is a" std::shared_ptr<myotherclass>.  This is probably not what you mean.

Comment: It's not "bad" so much as "weird". Surely that should be a member of `myotherclass` itself (or perhaps a non-member acting on `myotherclass`), not something bolted on to some specific smart pointer type?

Comment: If the pointer is `nullptr`, your `return 0;` is undefined behaviour, since you can't construct `std::string` with null pointer, see §21.4.2, 8 "Requires: `s` points to an array of at least `traits::length(s) + 1` elements of `charT`."

Comment: @milleniumbug edited to avoid this kind of confusion unrelated to the question. thanks for pointing out.

Comment: @drax http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_%28computer_science%29

Comment: It says `an allocation is never done` but then it referes to a new member named `info`. It looks like `info` must have been allocated as a member. What are you really doing?

Comment: @ribamar Sorry but there is no polymorphism in your example. Or do you mean to use a pointer on `std::shared_ptr<motherclass>` to store your `myclass` ? In that case as the accepted answer says it, don't do that :)

Comment: @drax: no, i didn't mean that. Can't you see the polymorphism on it? Consider `class Apple: public Fruit, public Food {... }`. Full polymorphism means that anytime you pass `Fruit` or `Food` you can provide `Apple`. In the same way, I meant a class that is polymorphic: something else (e.g, serializable, as  I could use with   `<<` to `cout`) and a `shared_ptr` at the same time.  (And my question, already answered,  wasn't if I shouldn't do that, it was why I shouldn't).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In principle it is allowed to derive from STL classes, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/922248/is-there-any-real-risk-to-deriving-from-the-c-stl-containers) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2034916/is-it-okay-to-inherit-implementation-from-stl-containers-rather-than-delegate). However, you have to be aware that you should not work with a pointer to the base class -- i.e. a `std::shared_ptr<myotherclass>*` in this case.

So this and variants thereof should be forbidden:

```
std::shared_ptr<myotherclass>* ptr = new myclass(/* ... */);
```

... but agreed, that looks a bit synthetic.

Why is it forbidden? Because the STL classes do not have a virtual destructor. So when you want to `delete` your allocated class, the derived part remains. This in turn invokes [undefined behaviour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8752111/possible-memory-leak-without-a-virtual-destructor) and possibly creates a memory leak -- even if you do not have some allocations in your derived class.

In order to do so, one possibility is to derive privately from `shared_ptr`:

```
class myclass : private std::shared_ptr<myotherclass> {};
                ^^^^^^^
```

This however might bring in problems with the binary compatibility, see the comments to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2035044/2412846).

On the hand, even though the former is allowed, you can go on less error-prone and either use composition, where you make the `shared_ptr` a member of `myclass` and expose the required functionality (with the drawback that you sometimes have to expose a lot). Or you can set up a standalone function which does what you want ... I know you knew that ;-)

Comment: `std::shared_ptr<myotherclass>* ptr = …` is nonsense. If a virtual destructor becomes necessary for an RAII class, something has already been badly abused.

Comment: @davidhigh - very complete answer: shows the limits of usability ("you should not work with a pointer to the base class"), points to references (in one of them I could see exactly where on the specification i was making mistake), and, demonstrates comprehension of that what the question maker was trying to achieve ("expose the required functionality (with the drawback that you sometimes have to expose a lot). Or you can set up a standalone function").

Comment: @Potatoswatter: `std::shared_ptr<myotherclass>* ptr = …` *is* nonsense, of course ... and in fact so absurd hopefully nobody will ever do it by mistake.

Answer (score 4):

Since you will never manually `delete` it (and you should never manually `delete` anything, which is rather the point of `shared_ptr` in the first place), virtual destructors aren't really an issue.

Some interoperability problems may come up, though.

1. You only get your derived class when you create specific instances of it. When you get a `shared_ptr` from somewhere like `get_shared_from_this`, it won't include your `info`.
2. Function templates overloaded on `shared_ptr<T>` won't see the inheritance. Your derived class will suddenly appear foreign to random functions such as `std::static_pointer_cast`.

Fortunately, the C++ standard library is full of neat extensibility hooks. You can install a custom deleter like so:

```
template< typename t >
struct my_deleter
    : std::default_delete< t > {
    std::string info;

    my_deleter( std::string in_info )
        : info( std::move( in_info ) ) {}
};

std::shared_pointer< foo > myfoo( new foo, my_deleter{ "it's a foo" } );
```

and retrieve the info with a non-member function:

```
template< typename t >
std::string get_my_info( std::shared_ptr< t > ptr ) {
    my_deleter< t > * dp = std::get_deleter< my_deleter< t > >( ptr );
    if ( ! dp ) return {};
    return dp->info;
}
```

This isn't a very good program architecture, since there's only one custom deleter slot per shared object. It can do in a pinch, though.

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest using `std::enable_shared_from_this<>` and then `this->shared_from_this()`.